# What are the options to integrate external data into Cloudera Impala?

Tags: postgresql, cloudera, impala, postgres-fdw

My use case is that I have an API to access SAP ERP data and would like to integrate both the meta-data (list of tables) and the actual data, so that Impala would join HDFS data with the data coming from my API. The best would be to use a similar method like PostgreSQL FDWs. Would like to hear opinions or even existing solutions for this problem.

All opinions, comments or thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot, David